# How to achieve this without using a photo editor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Can i change:

[image]

into:

[image]

without using a photo editor

- Here Is CSS and HTML code
- I couldn't upload the logo because i should have at least 10 reputation to post more than 2 links  so i maybe insert it in another comment

```css
header {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}

header .logo {
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  top: 13px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.background-image {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e5/%D0%94%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8F._%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B0.jpg/800px-%D0%94%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8F._%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B0.jpg') no-repeat center center;
  background-size: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="header-section logo">
      <a href="/">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/IB1gfZB.png" alt="...">
      </a>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="background-image"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Upload the picture to imgur or some photo sharing app and use that link of the image in your code here for the demo.

Comment: The snippet is not showing anything. Pleaze fix the `url` in the CSS.

Comment: Here is the logo http://imgur.com/a/nCh91

Comment: You can use any background picture

Comment: It might help clarify if you can describe specifically what you want to accomplish. For example, 50% opacity, a certain color adjustment, etc.

Comment: @showdev look at the logo in the two images

Comment: @sammichail Can you fix the snippett. I'll commit suicide if I give it one more try. CSS sucks.

Comment: I see the images. But it might help get an accurate answer if you describe what you're trying to accomplish. The visual difference between two images can be interpreted in many ways. (Is it just half-transparent? Do you want a specific blend mode like "multiply" or "color burn"? A hue or brightness change?)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `opacity` to create a semi-opaque image, and you may be fine with that by adjusting it to whatever you need.

But if you also want to change the color of the image darker, you can use CSS filters. You can make it darker/maroon/brown-ish by adjusting the hue. It's worth noting the browser support - https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters

```css
header {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}

header .logo {
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  top: 13px;
  max-width: 100%;
opacity: .7;
position: absolute;
top: 0; left: 0;
-webkit-filter: hue-rotate(45deg);
filter: hue-rotate(45deg);
}

.background-image {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff url(http://environment.umn.edu/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/global_landscapes_initiative_directory_pages.jpg) no-repeat center center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="header-section logo">
      <a href="/">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/IB1gfZB.png" alt="...">
      </a>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="background-image"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: @showdev not sure what you mean? Looks to me like the change they're trying to make is ~70% opacity and a little darker or brownish than the original image.

Comment: Agreed. I assumed the white text was part of the logo. But the OP has clarified that the logo consists of only the three red stripes.

Answer (score 0):

looks like **a one time thing** - i.e. it being a logo and all - It's just a lot easier to do such a thing with **Photoshop**.

I up-voted [Michael's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45023041/8157693) since I believe that's as close as you can get with **CSS alone**. Unless there's some "hacky" way to do this.

---

My method:

**Use Photoshop.**

Then add the photo as the background image of a one of the pseudo-elements for your header `div` / `img`

**I created a sample below** of the expected end result.

I encoded the overlay image as `Base64` since it's only `1kb` in size. It should be checked with your CSS file. Read more about [Base64](https://css-tricks.com/data-uris/)

You can control the `opacity` of the pseudo-element.

```css
.content {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
  background: url(https://unsplash.it/800/310) no-repeat
}

.content::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: .25;
  background: url('data:image/png;base64,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')
}
```

```html
<div class="content"></div>
```